# Start a Service without loading UI using JobScheduler

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service, android-jobscheduler, android-background

I have built an Application that sends some data to a Server. I am using a Job Scheduler Service that starts this service needed for the Application. It works fine when the Application is in Foreground or Background. But once the Application is Killed, the JobScheduler works fine but it is unable to start the service that is the base of the Application. Is there any specific way to start a service when an Application has been Killed by the OS? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I am using Android O and extending JobService for my Job Scheduler class!

Comment: Just send the data in the `JobService`. Or, use a foreground service and `startForegroundService()`. See https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background?hl=en#services

Comment: u may want to refer to this nice tutorial on using JobScheduler https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html. BTW, any specific reason to use JobScheduler ? WorkManager is recommended over JobScheduler as it comes with more features and internally uses JobScheduler on older OS versions.

Comment: The WorkManager API makes it easy to schedule deferrable, asynchronous tasks that are expected to run even if the app exits (your case) or device restarts. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/